# Setup a cron job in aws worker environment

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron

I have two php files regular.php & regular_with_argument.php
On cli I run these files by simply typing:

```
php regular.php
php regular_with_argument.php 1 (1 is the argument/parameter i pass)
```

I wanted to setup a cron.yaml in my aws elastic beanstalk worker environment.
So I followed the instructions on how to setup a crontab and this is what i got:

```
version: 1
cron:
- name: "Regular Report"
url: "/regular.php"
schedule: "45 4 * * *"
- name: "Regular With Argument Report"
url: "/regular_with_argument.php 1"
schedule: "20 4 4 * *"
```

My issue here is, the one with the argument does not work. Am I missing something here? The error is

ERROR: [Instance: i-0f20de5f1a4933d5b] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Failed of parsing file 'cron.yaml', because: bad URI(is not URI?): /php regular_with_argument.php 1 - (AWS::EB::SQSD::ScheduleParser::ScheduleFileError). 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/sqsd/hooks/start/02-start-sqsd.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to do this is to have your PHP parse $_GET['some_arg'] for arguments and then in your cron.yaml, set the url to:

```
url: "/regular_with_argument.php?some_arg=1"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try doing it your way.